# What is a good way to format a Duration object in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a java Duration object that should be formatted as `hh:mm:ss` in xml.

```
<Duration>${duration}</Duration>
```

But it is rendered with the standard format.

```
<Duration>PT30S</Duration>
```

I have a method in java that can format a duration and it is currently used for json mapping.

```
    public static String format(Duration value) {
        long hours = value.toHours();
        int minutes = value.toMinutesPart();
        int seconds = value.toSecondsPart();
        int millis = value.toMillisPart();
        return millis == 0
            ? String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
            : String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", hours, minutes, seconds, millis);
    }
```

I also need to render Duration in freemarker. Is it possible to use this same method in freemarker?

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in formatting for any of the Java 8 temporal classes as of FreeMarker 2.3.32. (Though there's a development branch with a semi-finished implementation, not even that addresses `Duration` yet.)

But, of course you can call static utility methods from FreeMarker. You have to put the value of this into the data-model (the template context), with the name you prefer (like `MyUtils` in this case) `((BeansWrapper) cfg.getObjectWrapper()).getStaticModels().get(MyUtils.class.getName())`, where `cfg` is the FreeMarker `Configuration` singleton.